# Java: Cannot return variable outside of try?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I keep getting the following error from the code below

**error:**

```
AccountController.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        return encoded;
               ^
  symbol:   variable encoded
  location: class AccountController
1 error
```

**code:**

```
public static String hash(String password) {
    try {       
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] byteOfTextToHash = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] hashedByetArray = digest.digest(byteOfTextToHash);
        String encoded;
        encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashedByetArray);

    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
    return encoded;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Your `encoded` variable is out of scope. Move it outside the try will fix this like:

```
public static String hash(String password) {
    String encoded = null;
    try {       
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] byteOfTextToHash = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] hashedByetArray = digest.digest(byteOfTextToHash);
        encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashedByetArray);

    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
    return encoded;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is `String encoded = null` to `String encoded = ""`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the varibale encoded outside try and initialize it with null or empty string as below

```
String encoded = "";
    try {
     ....
   }catch(Exception exc):\{
     ....
   }

  return encoded
```

;